# Apply cart rule discount in mini cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, mini-cart

I have implemented cart rules that gives discount when the user buys more than 20 items of a product.

The discount is shown in the cart, but not in the mini cart, which is very confusing for my customers.

How can I make the mini cart apply cart rules?

Comment: I also agree with this. I've only found an expensive module to help with this https://marketplace.magento.com/xumulus-cart-discount.html